# Posting Comment to Backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch

Attempting to post a comment on a portrait correctly using a JavasScript Frontend with a Rails backend.  The comment is posting, however on the frontend its showing it incorrectly.  When the user creates a comment, the comment does show however it always shows on the first portrait comment section when its posted.  However once you re-fresh the page it shows under the correct portrait.  I assume this is something to do with the way I am posting it to my backend in my POST.  This is what my current portraits code looks like used to build the portraits...

```
const buildPortrait = (portrait) => {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.className = 'card'
  div.id = portrait.id
  div.innerHTML = `
        <i class="far fa-window-close fa-1x" id="delete"></i>
        <img src= ${portrait.attributes.img_url} class="profile" alt="Avatar" >
        <div class="container">
        <h5 class='description'>Caption: ${portrait.attributes.description}</h5>
        <form data-portrait=${portrait.id} class="comment-form">
          <input
            class="comment-input"
            type="text"
            name="comment"
            placeholder="Add a comment..."
          />
          <button class="comment-button" type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
        <div class="likes-section">
        <button class="like-button"> ${portrait.attributes.like} likes ♥</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ` 
  cardContainer.appendChild(div)

  listenForLikes(portrait)
  commentSection(portrait)
  listenForComment(portrait)
  listenForEditComment(portrait)
  listenForDelete(portrait)
}
```

Below is the code I am attempting to use to build the comment and the have the POST correctly...

```
//create comments
  function commentSection(portrait){
      const newUl = document.createElement('ul')
      newUl.className = 'comments'
      
      portrait.attributes.comments.map(comment => {
        let li = document.createElement('li')
        li.textContent = comment.content
        newUl.appendChild(li)
        const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
        // editBtn.className = 'edit-button'
        editBtn.dataset.commentId = comment.id
        editBtn.innerHTML = `
         <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>` 
        // li.appendChild(editBtn)

      })
      const currentCard= document.getElementById(portrait.id)
      const description = currentCard.querySelector('.description')
      description.after(newUl)
    }
//event listen for comments
    function listenForComment(portrait){
      const portraitComment = document.getElementById(portrait.id)
      const commentForm = portraitComment.querySelector('.comment-form')
      commentForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        postComments(e)
        commentForm.reset()
      })
    }
//fetch comments
    function postComments(e){
      console.log()
      data = {
        content: e.target[0].value,
        portrait_id: e.target.dataset.portrait
      }
      console.log(data)

      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/comments`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.textContent = json["data"].attributes.content
        console.log(ul)
        ul.appendChild(li)
      })
    }
```

Any advice is gratefully appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to use something a lot more specific then `document.querySelector('ul')` if you intend to attach the comment to something else then the first `ul` element on in the document whatever that happens to be. Since you're passing the event as `e` to  `postComments` you can use `e.target` to get the form that was clicked. Its a pretty clunky way to write your code if you ask me. Shouldn't your function signature take some sensible arguments that tell you what you're commenting on?

Comment: And also your question doesnt actually tell use  what the document looks like or where you actually indend to add the new comment.